# Does anyone know the unit of scale used in scale parameter in ViewPointCenter?

Tags: c#, arcobjects

does anyone know the unit of scale used in scale parameter in ViewPointCenter? I've been looking this on the internet but haven't found anything yet. Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scale=>The scale at which the maps extent will be centered on. Scale is the ratio or relationship between a distance or area on a map and the corresponding distance or area on the ground, commonly expressed as a fraction or ratio. A map scale of 1/100,000 or 1:100,000 means that one unit of measure on the map equals 100,000 of the same unit on the earth. 
more info [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/store/api-reference/html/569fdfa9-2606-4db5-a591-fc99c107b2da.htm)

**Update:**
For example, on a 1:100000 scale map, 1cm on the map equals 1km on the ground.
more examples [here](https://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/national-location-information/topographic-maps-data/basics/what-is-map-scale)

Comment: Thank You sir!! I'd like to know whether it is in meter or